# Linking to boost through SConstruct

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, linker, scons

I'm trying to work on a cross-platform project that uses boost for the file/directory operations.  I've been using visual studio, but in order to compile on linux, I've decided to switch to SConstruct.

I cannot [correctly?] link to the filesystem library however.

my SConstruct file is as follow:

```
vLibs = [   
            'libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_44.lib',
            'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_44.lib'];
# LIBS=vLibs,
env = Environment();

env.AppendUnique(CXXFLAGS=Split("/EHsc"));
env.Append(CPPPATH = ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\boost\\boost_1_44"]);
env.Append(LIBPATH = ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\boost\\boost_1_44\\lib"]);

env.Program( Glob('test.cpp'),LIBS=vLibs)
```

I keep getting errors like

> test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'posix_category''(void)" (??__Eposix_category@system@boost@@YAXXZ)

If I use visual studio, I get similar errors:

> Error 2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)   T:\VS\temp\test.obj temp

Until I add the libraries to the project, after which the errors go away and it compiles fine (in visual studio not SConstruct).

I've tried every combination of the libraries (shared/unshared/runtime-shared/runtime-unshared/debug), but I always get the same errors.

I've been searching for an answer for the last 6+ hours, so I'm grateful for any help.

NOTE: I'm not using autolinking (#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB) because gcc doesn't support it)

Here's the output of Scons:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...


link /nologo /OUT:build\test.exe "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_44\lib" libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_44.lib     libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_44.lib build\test.obj
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl     boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'posix_category''(void)" (??    __Eposix_category@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl     boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'native_ecat''(void)" (??    __Enative_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
build\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
scons: *** [build\test.exe] Error 1120
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: Please post the link command line that scons is generating. Usually `LIBS` is a list of library names (e.g. `boost_system-vc100-mt-1_44`), not the full filenames.

Comment: Yeah, the lib extension shouldn't be on there, but it makes no difference either way - it gives the same errors without the extension. Here I copied the names verbatim to make sure that it worked in Visual Studio but not in scons.

Comment: Another guess: A previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066071/boost-linker-error-unresolved-external-symbol-class-boostsystemerror-catego) hints that it might be architecture problems: 32-bit vs 64-bit libraries.

Comment: I didn't see that question (wish I had though - would have saved me 6+ hours).  I had assumed that scons would use 32bit by default (like visual studio), but it doesn't.  "env = Environment(TARGET_ARCH='x86');" fixed the problem.  I'd really like to give you the answer Dave, you saved me from countless more hours of suffering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the exact same error until I rebuilt boost with the address-model=64 parameter to bjam

Comment: Marked this as the answer, but see mine below if you want to build the 32bit libraries.

Answer (score 2):

By default Boost builds for x86 and SConstruct builds by default for x64.  To change SConstruct to use x86, use `env = Environment(TARGET_ARCH='x86');` or to change Boost to x64, pass the `address-model=64` parameter to bjam.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the lib prefix nor suffix should be present.  Try these it like this in your SCons LIBS:

```
boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_44
```

Comment: Nope (tried both & various combinations of different libraries).  I know that its finding the libraries (because otherwise it complains that it can't find them).  The problem is that the linking isn't seeming to do anything.  I don't know if there's a special flag or what that I need to pass, but nothing seems to work.