# Have a static lib, is there a simple way to know it is for 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, 32bit-64bit

Is there any tool that can directly test if a library is made for 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use `dumpbin` utility with `/headers` option

It returns whether the library was built for 32 or 64 bit architecture.

Check [DUMPBIN Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference) for details.

Example usage:

```
c:\>dumpbin libXYZ.lib /headers
```

Comment: this does it, look for the 'FILE HEADERS' section

Answer (score 69):

Run a visual studio command prompt to ensure your path can find dumpbin.exe

Pipe to findstr to save on the big spew about each section and optionally you can use a wildcard to analyse a folder of libs.

`dumpbin /headers *.lib | findstr machine`

Example of what you're looking for;

```
8664 machine (x64)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but you can also use `file.exe`, the unix `file` equivalent on windows.
You can download the binary (and source as well) from [here](http://www.vowles-home.demon.co.uk/utils/windows_file_exe.htm) or gnu version [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: That's just the standard GNU File tool, right? I have tried this with `file` from a recent version of MinGW from Git for Windows, and it says `current ar archive` for the x64 `python36.lib` distributed with Python 3.6 (Windows).

Answer (score -1):

In visual studio, we can get to know about whether Lib/dll is 32 or 64 bit with Coreflags.exe
This tool is automatically installed with Visual Studio.
we can run this command from Command line, which can be run as

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\CorFlags.exe whatever_Lib_with_path
```

This command will return you whether that file is managed or Unmanaged.
If its **managed** then it can give info about that is is 32/64 bit.