# Linking .lib in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, dll, lib

I am trying to set VS (2015) project on Windows 10 to use external library however whatever I do I end up with LNK2019 errors.
If that helps library I am interested in is [CWO++](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cwolibrary/files/); I downloaded all the versions and tried them all, none worked. There are installation instructions available on library [site](http://cwolibrary.sourceforge.net/#inst), however following them yeilded no success.

What I did:

[WINDOWS]

- I organized each of library version root directory to consist of 2 sub-directories:

  - **src** - containing all `.h`, `.cpp` files
  - **bin** - containing all `.lib`, `.dll` files
- Set up `CWO_PATH` envirnoment variable pointing to version I was trying out at the moment, for instance `CWO_PATH` = `D:\Coding\cwo\0.20`
- Added both directories - that is **src** and **bin** - to the PATH for instance: `D:\Coding\cwo\0.20\bin` and `D:\Coding\cwo\0.20\src` (as instructed on the [site](http://cwolibrary.sourceforge.net/#inst)).
- Also checked just in case whether `.lib` files are indeed 64-bit as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014107/have-a-static-lib-is-there-a-simple-way-to-know-it-is-for-32-bit-or-64-bit)

[VISUAL STUDIO]

- Created empty c++ project
- Edited properties of x64 configuration:
- C/C++/General tab, in Additional Include Directories added `$(CWO_PATH)/src`
- Linker/General tab, in Additional Library Directories added `$(CWO_PATH)/bin`
- Linker/Input tab, in Additional Dependencies added `cwo.lib;` in the beginning
- Added `main.cpp` with following code

```
#include <cwo.h>

int main()
{
    CWO c;
}
```

After building the project I get 3 errors:
[image]

Im assuming that the library is not linked properly. Can you please tell me what is wrong with this configuration?

EDIT
Linker settings
[image]
[image]
Windows lib directory
[image]

Comment: can you take a screen shot of your linker settings just to double check, maybe there is a typo. Can you also confirm with windows explorer that the files are located where you expect them to be.

Comment: While you might have set the x64 settings, that is not what you actually built.  I can tell from `_main`, that leading underscore only appears in a x86 build.  Get ahead with Build > Configuration Manager.  And when you make such setting changes, ensure that the two comboboxes at the top of the dialog are set to "All..."

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez screenshots uploaded

Comment: @HansPassant I can try that, thanks

Comment: From the screenshot, it is visible, that you are switching between configurations (*Active(x64)* and *Active(Win 32)*). Make sure, that you configured the project in all combinations of Configuration and Platform.

Comment: @Zereges unifying configurations yeilded same results - LNK2019 - does not matter if I run x64 or x86 build.

Comment: @michelson I tried the library at home, and i get the same results as you.

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez thanks a lot! I think it means that something is wrong with .lib itself. I wanted to avoid it but I guess I have to compile it myself...

Comment: @michelson I did the same and tried the library myself and latest version even contains a typo in source, which made it non compilable, which literally means, that the `.lib` file doesn't correspond to source files.

Comment: @Zereges yes, I had some problems with source as well... I will try each versions' source - maybe one of them is reliable. Else I will have to apply 'fixes' on my own and try to compile it somehow. Thanks for help!