# Unresolved external symbol at boost::system::error_category

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I would like to build my program on x86 Windows 7, which used the boost library. After reading the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1067072/2609713) I tried to build boost and compile my program in debug mode. The output dialog in Visual Studio 2010 throws the following errors:

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
...`

I've used the following build commands to build boost:
`bjam --build-dir=c:\boost --build-type=complete --toolset=msvc-10.0 address-model=64 architecture=x86 -j 4` Note: command `--with-system` is not working for me.

My Project Settings are: `Project->Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories: D:\boost\boost_1_57_0;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)` and `Project->Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories: D:\boost\boost_1_57_0\stage\lib`

How can I solve the unresolved external symbol errors?

Comment: Have you checked the `D:\boost\boost_1_57_0\stage\lib` directory whether the library file exists? You should see something similar to `libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_57.lib/dll`

Comment: yes, this file is available...do you have an other idea?

Comment: Could be something going wrong with auto linking. Try setting the linker to verbose mode (Show Progress option) and see what libraries it's attempting to link to.

Comment: @Praetorian I have cleaned my project and included each single library. The main problem is the asio library. I will  try setting the linker to verbose mode and give you a response.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem. I've recompiled the boost library 1.57 with the following command: `b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete --libdir=C:\boost\lib\x64 architecture=x86 address-model=64 install`. Maybe, you should add the argument `j%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%` to speed up the compile process.

Note:
The main different to the command in my question is, that I use in this case `b2` instead of `bjam`.