# Hitting a LNK2019 error trying to link Boost with CMake

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, cmake

I am making my first project that is using CMake for the build system. I also decided this would be a good time to try to incorporate boost into my c++ skills. I've read through the documentation and flipped through SO and other sites, but I'm getting stuck on an LNK2019 error. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066071/boost-linker-error-unresolved-external-symbol-class-boostsystemerror-categ) that this could be due to a 32/64 bit project / boost library mismatch. However, I am reasonably confident I build the right libraries. I'll post the relevant cmake, code, errors, and commands below

Build Command

```
b2.exe -a variant=debug,release link=shared,static threading=multi address-model=64
```

Generate Project Command

```
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 12 Win64"
```

CMake File

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Thoth)

add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB )
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF )
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

configure_file (
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/main.h"
  )

set(BOOST_ROOT D:/Programs/boost_1_58_0)
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR ${BOOST_ROOT})
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib/)
find_package(Boost 1.58.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

add_executable(Thoth main.cpp)

include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})
link_directories(${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})

target_link_libraries( Thoth $(Boost_LIBRARIES))
```

C++ File

```
#define BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

#include "main.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    string line;
    ifstream input("../images/source/balls2.nff", ios::in);
    if (!input){
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        while (getline(input, line)){
            cout << line << '\n';
        }

        input.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio Output

```
------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
------ Build started: Project: Thoth, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'native_ecat''(void)" (??__Enative_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'errno_ecat''(void)" (??__Eerrno_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
C:\Users\JR\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\thoth\_build64\Debug\Thoth.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
------ Skipped Build: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

Hopefully I overlooked something stupid, but I've been reading through other people's answers and not getting anywhere for a little bit. I figured it was time to ask for some help.

**After Feedback**

I'll keep the most up to date CMake and debug output here. So that other users (or me) can compare the original and final code.

CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Thoth)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF )
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

configure_file (
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/main.h"
  )

set (Boost_DEBUG ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT D:/Programs/boost_1_58_0)
find_package(Boost 1.58.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS ${BOOST_ROOT})
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS ${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib/)
set(Boost_LIBRARIES ${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib/)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARIES})

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

add_executable(Thoth main.cpp)

if (WIN32)
    add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB )
    add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK )
endif()

target_link_libraries( Thoth $(Boost_LIBRARIES))
```

CMake Command Output With Debug On (Removed full path to FindBoost for readability)

```
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 12 Win64"
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:513 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS =
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:515 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = ON
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:517 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = OFF
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:519 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = OFF
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:521 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS =
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:523 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS =
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:575 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:577 ]   BOOST_ROOT = D:/Programs/boost_1_58_0
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:579 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR =
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:581 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR =
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:583 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS =
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:652 ] Include debugging info:
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:654 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS =
D:/Programs/boost_1_58_0/include;D:/Programs/boost_1_58_0;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:656 ]   _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES =
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:676 ] location of version.hpp: D:/Programs/boost_1_58_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:700 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.58.0
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:785 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -vc120
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:795 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:838 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:840 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -gd
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:888 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = D:/Programs/boost_1_58_0/lib;D:/Programs/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib;D:/Programs/boost_1_58_0/lib;D:/Programs/boost_1_58_0/../lib;D:/Programs/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:998 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-vc120-mt-1_58;boost_system-vc120-mt;boost_system-mt-1_58;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:1034 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_58;boost_system-vc120-mt-gd;boost_system-mt-gd-1_58;boost_system-mt-gd;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:998 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_58;boost_filesystem-vc120-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-1_58;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:1034 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_58;boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd;boost_filesystem-mt-gd-1_58;boost_filesystem-mt-gd;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ FindBoost.cmake:1085 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
  --   system
  --   filesystem
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/JR/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/thoth/_build64
```

Comment: Set variable `Boost_DEBUG` before find_package(Boost) and verify, that printed values of `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS` and `Boost_LIBRARIES` variables are expected. BTW, it is better to use these variables (prefixed with `Boost_)`instead of preassigned ones (prefixed with `BOOST_`) after `find_package(Boost)` call.

Comment: I followed your suggestions as best I was able. (I also moved my add definitions on the advice of another SO user). I am still getting LNK2019 errors. From looking over the debug output, I see it searching over the rights directories. It seems to find the proper Boost libraries. My next assumption is that I'm misusing the LINK_DIRECTORIES or TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES command. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, in regard to setting Boost_* or BOOST_* variables, I've seen other SO users use either with no explanation. What's the reasoning behind setting one over the other?

Comment: Difference between BOOST_* and Boost_* variables is that the first ones are **input** parameters for `find_package(Boost)`, while the second ones are **output**. Sometimes output parameters are just copies of input ones, but it is not always true. Also, using output parameters are less error-prone: even if  you will decide to not define some input parameters in the future, output ones remains defined anyway. In your **After Feedback** variant *output* variables are reset *after* `find_package` - this is incorrect, you should use ones returned by `find_package` call.

Comment: I found that `Boost_DEBUG` do not print all output variables. While `version.h` file is found properly, it is better to check also value of output variables, listed in my first comment: just print them via `message(STATUS)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two fairly trivial issues here which should hopefully be easy to fix.

The first is that `find_package(Boost ...)` is probably doing its job correctly, i.e. it's setting good values for `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS` and `Boost_LIBRARIES`.  However, you immediately overwrite these variables by calling the three `set` commands!  So you should remove those three commands.

The other issue is in your `target_link_libraries` call - you've accidentally used parentheses rather than braces when trying to dereference `Boost_LIBRARIES` - i.e. change `$(Boost_LIBRARIES)` to `${Boost_LIBRARIES}`.

By the way, there are a couple of other points which are unrelated to the issue:

1. You shouldn't generally set `BOOST_ROOT` like that inside the CMakeLists.txt.  It's really meant to be set by passing it as a `-D` arg on the command line (or via the CMake GUI) so that it's not hard-coded to a value specific to your own individual machine.
2. You don't need the `link_directories` call.  Its [own documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/link_directories.html) discourages its use:

   > Note that this command is rarely necessary. Library locations returned by `find_package()` and `find_library()` are absolute paths. Pass these absolute library file paths directly to the `target_link_libraries()` command. CMake will ensure the linker finds them.

Comment: I marked yours as the answer. I also had my definitions in the wrong place  (ie at the end of the file) because of ... lack of sleep? I had two follow up questions if you don't mind. 1) Looking at the help file, I see that -D is used to "Create a cmake cache entry". Im not sure how that accomplishes setting BOOST_ROOT. 2) I haven't searched extensively for this, but I had to copy the two dlls I needed to the directory with my exe file. What's considered best practice around this?

Comment: 1) On the command line, you'd run something like `cmake . -DBOOST_ROOT=D:/Programs/boost_1_58_0`.  This would set and cache the value (similar to calling `set(... CACHE ...)` - see [the docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/set.html#set-cache-entry)).  2) It's a big topic!  My own preference is always to avoid DLL Hell by using static libraries.  It looks like you're already building the static versions of the Boost libs - you'd just have to tell CMake to use them by changing `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to `ON`.

Comment: Great! thanks for the advice on number 2. And on #1 I took it too literally (trying to set -D D:/path